# Should custom login flows be pulled by sfdx force:source:pull

Tags: salesforcedx, loginflow

If I create a custom Login Flow in a scratch org, and then pull using `sfdx force:source:pull`, should I expect that flow to be pulled down as source? The flow created in Flow Builder is pulled, just not the "Login Flow".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/46) is the centralized location for which metadata elements are supported by functionality like Salesforce DX and the Metadata API.

The `LoginFlow` component is not supported by source tracking, which drives `sfdx force:source:pull`. It's also not supported by the Metadata API or any version of packaging. Unfortunately, you won't be able to store this component in source form other than the flow definition you've retrieved already.